# Delphi pointer arithmetic

Tags: delphi

How should this line of code be writed to allow it to compile

```
MoveMemory(poleFileDescriptorW
         , (oleDataPointer + SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW) *Index + 4)^
         , SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW));
```

Particularly this part

**`(oleDataPointer + SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW)*Index + 4)^`**

I am just want to shift the pointer by `SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW)*Index + 4` bytes

Variables are defined as:

```
pOLEFileDescriptorW : ^FILEDESCRIPTORW;
oleDataPointer : Pointer;
```

Comment: What are the types of the variables you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast to an integer type, do the math and cast back.

I usually used `Cardinal` but I think that doesn't work with a 64 bit compiler.

`Pointer(NativeInt(oleDataPointer) + SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW)*Index + 4)`

Comment: Delphi is still 32-bit only. It doesn't matter what kind of OS you have. On a 64-bit OS, the program will run emulated under WOW.

Comment: There is *still* no 64 bit version of Delphi? Still I'd like my code to work with future 64 bit delphi compilers(or 64bit freepascal)

Comment: @CodeInChaos: You can use the `NativeUInt` type.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: In which Delphi version did they introduce `NativeUInt`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It exists at least in Delphi 2009 (and 2010, XE).

Comment: I think if you use a new Delphi version you could also use generics to define helper methods for pointer arithmetic.

Comment: You can use a PByte (or a PAnsiChar) and do pointer arithmetic directly that way

Comment: I thought pointer arithmetic directly on a pointer type is only possible in FreePascal, not Delphi? Is it really possible with PByte?

Comment: Delphi > 2009 eventually allows pointer arithmetics, just set $POINTERMATH ON.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: can you confirm that NativeInt/UInt actually exist in D2009?  I thought they were introduced in D2010.

Comment: AFAIK NativeInt was introduced in D2007 but the declaration there is wrong (64 bit). It should have been fixed in D2009 (I skipped it so I can't check).

Answer (score 7):

If you're using DELPHI >= 2009, set $POINTERMATH to ON and you can use pointer arithmetic directly

Answer (score 2):

`MoveMemory` and the identical `CopyMemory` functions accept *pointers*, not variables, as the Delphi RTL function `Move` requires (and this is the only difference between `MoveMemory` and `Move`).

So you shouldn't dereference the pointer. Just do

```
MoveMemory(poleFileDescriptorW,
           (oleDataPointer + SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW)*Index + 4),
           SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW));
```

where each argument is a pointer/cardinal. Depending on your actual data types, you might need to do some trivial casting. For instance, you might need to do `PSomeType(cardinal(myPointer) + cardinal(myPointer2))`.

Anyhow, if you would sometime need to dereference a pointer, you need to specify its type.

```
(oleDataPointer + SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW)*Index + 4)^
```

couldn't possibly work (why?). Do

```
PMyType(cardinal(oleDataPointer) + SizeOf(oleFileDescriptorW)*Index + 4)^
```

Answer (score 1):

Typecast to Integer.

```
 Pointer(Integer(oleDataPointer) + SizeOf(oleFileDescriptionW) * Index + 4)
```

And [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303880/delphi-pointer-arithmetic/4303955#4303955) was right that you should use pointers directly.
See if that works.

God bless

Comment: You should cast to `cardinal`, not `integer` (why?)! Also, `MoveMemory`/`CopyMemory` requires pointers, not variables, so you shouldn't dereference (as in the `Move` case).

Comment: I'd prefer an unsigned integer type, but that's mostly a stylistic issue. But your code can fail if integer overflow checks are on(they're off by default)

Comment: @andreas Why not Integer? Does Delphi do a conversion and looses data on overflow?

Comment: @codeinchaos Oh I see. Thanks for the explanation, didn't remember about the possibility of Delphi checking for integer overflow.

Comment: It doesn't matter much in practice since doing pointer-as-integer/cardinal and int overflow checking don't work well in practice anyways. So you should disable these checks in these code parts.